# zipgrep with wildcard to match multiple files

Tags: macos, zip, zgrep

How to unzip multiple zip archives using a wildcard with `zipgrep`:

```sh
$ zipgrep statistics.*.zip
```

```
caution: filename not matched:  statistics.2021-02-19.1.log.zip
caution: filename not matched:  statistics.2021-02-19.2.log.zip
caution: filename not matched:  statistics.2021-02-19.3.log.zip
/usr/bin/zipgrep: line 97: test: -eq: unary operator expected
/usr/bin/zipgrep: line 100: test: : integer expression expected
```

I'm expecting the same output as with `zgrep` over matching gz and plain text files.

The output is for MacOS

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/searching-for-a-string-on-multiple-zip-files